# Identifying a SSOP (standard sum of products) expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

Say you're asked to identify a standard sum of products (SSOP) expression from 4 or 5 options...

3 of them are definitely not SSOP (variables are missing between the terms)... however two of the options are...

1. None of the above.
2. AB'.

Solution: It is possible for AB' to be of SSOP form. Not knowing the domain allows this to be constructed.

Z = AB' is valid & of SSOP form...

| A | B | Z |

| 0 | 0 | 0 |

| 0 | 1 | 0 |

| 1 | 0 | 1 |

| 1 | 1 | 0 |

Comment: `AB'` can be the answer if it is a two variable function.

Comment: The domain isn't given for any of the expressions. I'm thinking you can't guarantee AB' to be in SSOP form.